# New to Email Parser in Java, facing issue when reading the subject

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How do I read the original subject of the kick back email received from the mail delivery system.

I am doing it this way: `messageSubject = message.getSubject();` which actually returns the wrong one i.e ”Delivery status notification” (this one I can see under subject of view message details of kick back email).

Comment: Please include more examples of your code, add also exported email content so whe can see headers and such.

Comment: You need to parse the message, a Delivery Status Notification (DSN) usually contains the headers of the original email (or possibly the full original email) as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for a "bounce" email that you get in response to an email that cannot be delivered to have a different subject to the email that you sent.  The original email may be included as an attachment to the notification.

The responses that you get in this scenario are not standardized and vary from one mail server (MTA) to another.  If you are going to process them automatically, you will need to understand the structure of the responses you are getting from your MTA and potentially the remote MTA that are bouncing the emails.

You should probably start by looking at the bounce emails in your email to get an idea of their structure.